# Download file using jQuery from an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, download

I am working on the front end of a java application, I am doing a request to our backend API to download a report (that I believe) is created on the fly in the backend and then the files are generated and zipped for download.

I pass some parameters to the API, to add options / filters to the reports to be generated. The API if everything goes well starts the download (I can hit the API service directly in the browser). If an error happens with the selected options filters I get an error message as a plain string.

So as I see it, I need to verify if everything is fine with the selected filters, if not I catch the string and display the message to the user, if everything is fine I start the download.

I am doing this, in a rather dummy way. First I do an AJAX request to the API, and see if the request fails, if it is I display the message in an alert. If it is successful I do a subsequent call to the API (exact same URL) as a form submit to start the file download.

Now my problem is that the backend might take a long time to generate the files and all, and do two request to the same URL, seems clumsy to say the least. I would like to know it there is a way for me to see if I get errors from the API, otherwise download the file all with the same request. Is it possible?

This is a snippet of what I am currently doing:

```
        //sUrl gets formed according to the selected options in a form
        ajaxConfig = {
            url         : sUrl,
            type        : 'GET',
            async       : true,
            cache       : false,
            success     : function(date) {


                jQuery('<form action="'+ sUrl+'" method="'+ ('get') +'">'+inputs+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();


            },
            error       : function(msg) {
                alert('error: ' + msg.responseText);

            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
```